Failed to Acquire Lock Downloading Maven Dependancy
I have this single project dependandcy and every time it tries to download it it downloads stuff for about 2 minutes and then fails with just "Could not acquire lock(s)"
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
      <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

pom and error
I don't even know what to try to solve this, I am just lost.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

first trying on plain command line not from your IDE... furthermore please give more details which Maven version do you use? Which JDK version... also your full pom file ...
